# Profiling and debugging of OpenCL with MPI is supported in CodeXL?

Tags: debugging, profiling, opencl, mpi, amd-processor

I would like to know whether the CodeXL from AMD supports debugging and profiling of applications with both MPI & OpenCL components in a cluster environment.

Comment: This is a question that's probably better directed at the AMD team (http://devgurus.amd.com/community/codexl). They'll be much more likely to be able to tell you about their product.

Answer (score 0):

The latest CodeXL to date (CodeXL 1.4, released Apr-2014) provides debugging and profiling of OpenCL apps on a single station. This release does not support MPI or cluster environments.